# How can I run commands from Jenkins on a remote machine as root?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, jenkins, ssh

I tried using both the SSH and Publish Over SSH plugins but the `sudo su` command just hangs and then times out. I need to be logged in as root in the remote machine to run a few commands. The ubuntu user has root privileges and `sudo su` works from the command line. Can someone please tell me what I could be doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Considering `few commands`, you can just `sudo` each command that you need to execute. Sometimes a timeout is related to ssh authentication (verification strategy), did you check if using non-root commands works as expected? Also, check if the node is properly connected?

Comment: @sumitani Thanks for the reply. I tried adding sudo before commands and that didn't actually work. The remote machine I'm trying to connect to has [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) running on it as root and sudo followed by vault commands do not work, both from the command line of the vault machine and Jenkins.
So something like `sudo vault status` does not work but `sudo su` followed by `vault status` does.

Comment: @sumitani Also, non-root commands do work as expected. I can run all commands as ubuntu user. So I'm guessing the connection between Jenkins and the remote machine has been established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your remote server allows for direct login then this should work,

`ssh -l root (server name) (command_to_execute)`

Check if the SSH process is running.
If your connection hangs and times out, check the SSH port 22 is open, if you can connect to this port from your Jenkins server.

Running commands as root are not recommended, and using a non root user with the permissions is advised.

Also try and ping and see if there any lost packets, from your local PC to the remote server and the hosts file, to see if the local machine can connect to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Although this does work, unfortunately it is not an option as we cannot enable root login on these machines.

Answer (score 0):

After `sudo su - user` put the commands between <<eso and eos:

```
execCommand: 'sudo su - user <<eos \n' +              
'command1 \n' +              
'command2 \n' +              
'etc....  \n' +              
'eos'
```